# Django url match not matching for rule in urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^page/\w+/$', get_page),
    (r'', main),
)
```

calling : http://localhost:8081/page/cricket

calls the **main**, function and not **get_page**

How can I make this work?

Comment: are you trying to pass the value after page into your get_page function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression is wrong.  It would match http://localhost:8081/page/cricket/ or http://localhost:8081/page/dog/.  It does not match http://localhost:8081/page/cricket because the regular expression requires a / at the end.

Based on your comments and question you may want something like:

```
   (r'^page/(?P<loc>.*)', get_page)
```

This would also pass everything after `page/` to the the get_page function in the named parameter 'loc'.

If you're having trouble with the meaning of the special symbols please refer to [Python's regular expression reference](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

`^page/\w+/$'` is a regex which matches a string starting `page/`, followed by one or more letters, followed by `/` and having no more characters.

`page/cricket` contains the first two of those elements, but not the third, and so does not match.